# How can I source every available `source_me` in the current path?

Tags: shell, tcsh

Say I have a path like `./src/system/subsystem/subsubsystem` and each of `system`, `subsystem`, and `subsubsystem` have a file called `source_me`. How can I create a script to `source` each one of those in the current environment?

#### Example Use

```
$ cat > $HOME/bin/source_all
???
$ chmod a+x $HOME/bin/source_all
$ cd ~/src/system/subsystem/subsubsystem

$ source_all
> Sourcing /home... no such file
> Sourcing /home/user... no such file
> Sourcing /home/user/src...
(hello from src/source_me!)

> Sourcing /home/user/src/system...
(hello from system/source_me!)

> Sourcing /home/user/src/system/subsystem...
(hello from subsystem/source_me!)

> Sourcing /home/user/src/system/subsystem/subsubsystem...
(hello from subsubsystem/source_me!)

> Done.
```

Comment: You can `cd ..` until you reach root and then use the directory stack (`$dirstack[]`) to go back. You may want to clear the stack with `dirs -c` before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand your question on my first answer, I hope I did this time:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
foreach f (`pwd | awk -F'/' '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print path = path"/"$i }'`)

    echo "> Sourcing $f..."

    if (-e $f/source_me) then
        source $f/source_me
    else
        echo "no such file"
    endif
end
```

I'm using `awk` with `pwd` to generate all the parent folders, and then test if `source_me` exists or not in this folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get `[1]: echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
[2]: cat ~/bin/source_all
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
# -*- mode: sh -*-

...
[3]: source_all
for: Command not found.
do: Command not found.
f: Undefined variable.`

Comment: Probably becase you're using `tcsh`. Add `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of the script.

Comment: Well, this question *is* tagged `tcsh`... Will I be able to use the bash script from tcsh?  (I have to use the latter for work.)

Comment: So sorry... I did not see the tag... I will try to edit my answer, but I won't be able to test it.

Comment: Fair enough :) I'm sure this answer works for bash though, so it's definitely useful!